# How to search recursively for a string in a prompt in windows?

Tags: windows, search, prompt

I've installed `unixutils`,and `grep string *` can search `string` in the current directory,

but how to make it search **recursively**?

Comment: Here's what I use with unixutils, because searching for all file types might slow me down. Note you can also change . to a different directory if you want: grep -r --include "file_pattern" -i "my_text" .

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-R` switch for a recursive search (or `-r` or `--recursive`).

from the man page:

```
-R, -r, --recursive
          Read all files under each directory, recursively; this is equiv-
          alent to the -d recurse option.
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you don't need `grep`-specific functionality: Windows supports this out of the box anyway:

```
findstr /s "string"
```